# php-Ajax: Send Float data and get response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Ajax Script**

```
<script>
function tankdip(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("open").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
    var num = parseFloat(str);
        var tank = document.getElementById("pumps"+count).value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("open").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","open.php?open="+num+"&tank="+tank,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

**Html Form**

```
<td><input type="text" name="odip[]"   id="odip" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm " onkeyup="tankdip(this.value)" required></td>
<td><select  name="open[]"  id="open" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm " readonly></select></td>
```

**open.php**

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name")or die("Your Connection is in error");
$open = $_GET['open'];
$tank    = $_GET['tank'];
$sql     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT dip,cap from $tank where dip = '$open'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$combo.="<option >" . $row[1]. "</option>";
}

echo $combo;

?>
```

I want to get the "open" value using ajax for corresponding "odip" value. But when i try to send in float (12.34) it goes as (12).I want the date to be sent as Float.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function tankdip(str) {
  console.log("Input str:", str);
```

A your sure what `str` is float?

Also may be so what field `dip` in some table has a INT-type ?

Comment: str prints  float value but when it goes to php script it goes as int